# Connection between Abstract Integral and Riemann Integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function on the interval $[a, b]$, we define $g(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(y) dy $, prove that $g(x)$ is continuous on interval $(a, b)$.

I first thought of rewriting the definition of $g(x)$ as an abstract integral:
$$g(x) = \int_{[a, x]} f d\lambda $$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and then try to show that $|g(x)  - g(c)| < \epsilon$, when $|x-c| < \delta(\epsilon)$. (Which I think I can do)

The **main doubt** is : Is this conversion to an abstract integral valid?

Comment: "Integrable" is ambiguous. But [Riemann = Lebesgue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2278425) (but the equality is not reflexive here ; ))

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278425/riemann-integrable-implies-lebesgue-integrable?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If by "integrable" you mean "Riemann integrable" then $f$ is bounded, so $g$ is Lipschitz continuous, by the obvious estimate.